# trying to to import tflearn, but something is missing

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, tflearn

I was trying to import tflearn in th python shell.

But i receive an error

```
import tflearn

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
ImportError: No module named google.protobuf
>>>
```

Comment: `pip install protobuf`?

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you running ? Can you import tensorflow properly ?

Answer (score 0):

As sygi suggested:  `pip install protobuf`.

(Otherwise, this question needs more answers to the questions raised a year ago in comments.)